# Button text is cut off in grid

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

If I have a button in a StackLayout I can write as much text as I want and the button gets bigger automatically. But if I have two buttons next to each other in a grid it doesn't work and the text is cut off.

```
<StackLayout>
                        
                        <Button
                            FontSize="Large"
                            Style="{DynamicResource PrimaryColorFullButton}"
                            Text="{resources:TranslateExtensions ErrorConnectionMessage}"
                            Command="{Binding ExecuteLoginCommand}" />
                    
                        <Grid
                            RowDefinitions="*,50"
                            ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                    
                            <Button
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Text="{resources:TranslateExtensions NewAccount}"
                                Command="{Binding ExecuteRegistrationCommand}"
                                Style="{DynamicResource TransparentFullButtonStyle}">
                            </Button>
                    
                            <Button 
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Text="{resources:TranslateExtensions LoginForgotten}"
                                Command="{Binding ExecuteForgotPasswordCommand}"
                                Style="{DynamicResource TransparentFullButtonStyle}">
                            </Button>
                    
                        </Grid>    
                    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

how can I prevent the text from being cut off?

Comment: you are assigning a fixed height to the grid row

Comment: öhm no... it's the grid like this in the code above

Comment: Dario, yes you did. Look again. Your Grid's RowDefinitions has a height of 50 on Row 1. It's in your code above.

Comment: Ah yes right but this is on second row this 50. The buttons are on the first row... .:-)

Comment: Is the `StackLayout` inside another layout or grid container? Something is limiting the height of the grid. Is there additional space available below, not shown in image? If so, then the problem is that at layout time, the buttons don't realize they need more than one text line to show the text. To give more advice, need to see more XAML, to understand the overall structure. Try to "flatten" the layout, instead of nesting containers inside containers. Usually a single `Grid` is sufficient, with appropriate use of `RowSpan`/`ColumnSpan`.

Comment: Steve thanks for your answer, the Grid was in a StackLayout and this has caused the problem. When I remove the StackLayout the the texts on the button are no longer cut off... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `,50` from your Grid's RowDefinitions.

```
<Grid 
    RowDefinitions="*" 
    ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
```

It is reserving a blank/white rectangle with a height of 50 at the bottom of your StackLayout's available space, which is cutting off your buttons which are on Row 0.

Comment: The answer might be correct, but its explanation could be improved. `,50` is reserving 50 at bottom of available space, for (unused) row 1. This reduces the height available for row 0, so the buttons don't fit, get cut off.

Comment: Thanks, ToolmakerSteve. Clarification edited into my answer.